# Extract different set of rows from data frames in list

Tags: r, dataframe

It is going to be hard to give you a reproducible example but in general it supposed to be an easy task for many of you. My brain has not yet switched on after midday coffee.

I have a list of 20-30 data frames. I would like to extract specific rows from each data frame. The pattern will be very repetetive.

From first data frame, lets call it `LD1` I would like to take rows `1:8` and from every next data frame the row numbers will be higher by `8`, so `9:16`, third - `17:24`, etc.

I would like to keep original names of these data frames.

Can someone switch a light in my brain ?

Comment: what do you do with the rows you extract? you create a new dataframe?

Comment: I will do some calculations with them, plotting and finally printing out for a report. For now each data frame contains of thousands of rows when I need only few 8-12 of them. However, they are located in different "places" in each data frame from a list.

Comment: I think it should be `17:24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use `Map` and create the indices using a simple mathematical formula which will work for any number of data frames in your list, i.e.

```
Map(function(x, y)x[seq(8) + y * 8,, drop = FALSE], l2, 0:(length(l2) - 1))
```

which gives,

```
$v1
   v1
1 444
2  52
3 345
4  48
5 375
6 491
7  10
8 126

$v1
    v1
9   57
10 354
11 239
12 205
13 273
14 172
15 345
16 293

$v1
    v1
17 366
18 487
19 423
20 194
21  18
22 476
23 151
24 382

$v1
    v1
25 131
26 245
27  10
28  41
29 248
30 104
31 163
32 187

$v1
    v1
33 335
34  44
35 442
36 362
37 470
38 145
39 384
40 257
```

where `l2`,

```
dput(l2)
list(v1 = structure(list(v1 = c(444L, 52L, 345L, 48L, 375L, 491L, 
10L, 126L, 231L, 124L, 494L, 476L, 213L, 208L, 35L, 327L, 294L, 
467L, 39L, 295L, 12L, 49L, 201L, 335L, 72L, 204L, 453L, 299L, 
157L, 355L, 380L, 348L, 309L, 117L, 404L, 304L, 222L, 287L, 500L, 
406L, 340L, 166L, 442L, 256L, 354L, 269L, 98L, 245L, 471L, 253L, 
15L, 130L, 434L, 329L, 465L, 18L, 346L, 389L, 185L, 238L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame"), v1 = structure(list(v1 = c(67L, 
461L, 68L, 420L, 59L, 291L, 391L, 275L, 57L, 354L, 239L, 205L, 
273L, 172L, 345L, 293L, 236L, 304L, 70L, 410L, 91L, 204L, 343L, 
386L, 400L, 482L, 221L, 190L, 340L, 328L, 367L, 36L, 95L, 229L, 
98L, 148L, 255L, 490L, 101L, 480L, 113L, 122L, 330L, 31L, 276L, 
18L, 192L, 243L, 178L, 240L, 297L, 75L, 381L, 144L, 71L, 208L, 
76L, 46L, 146L, 373L)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"), 
    v1 = structure(list(v1 = c(344L, 200L, 282L, 236L, 404L, 
    201L, 286L, 185L, 479L, 46L, 32L, 124L, 365L, 297L, 66L, 
    483L, 366L, 487L, 423L, 194L, 18L, 476L, 151L, 382L, 240L, 
    261L, 346L, 345L, 85L, 332L, 179L, 67L, 87L, 415L, 98L, 480L, 
    320L, 307L, 141L, 224L, 27L, 432L, 103L, 23L, 370L, 306L, 
    153L, 78L, 418L, 186L, 459L, 162L, 59L, 484L, 20L, 385L, 
    216L, 116L, 99L, 301L)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"), 
    v1 = structure(list(v1 = c(358L, 233L, 343L, 121L, 22L, 230L, 
    461L, 430L, 246L, 19L, 155L, 303L, 197L, 276L, 44L, 264L, 
    102L, 243L, 153L, 385L, 89L, 49L, 360L, 148L, 131L, 245L, 
    10L, 41L, 248L, 104L, 163L, 187L, 5L, 179L, 341L, 322L, 250L, 
    210L, 223L, 103L, 80L, 151L, 263L, 310L, 34L, 275L, 165L, 
    328L, 71L, 364L, 454L, 336L, 249L, 205L, 284L, 419L, 113L, 
    185L, 416L, 298L)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"), 
    v1 = structure(list(v1 = c(393L, 346L, 227L, 242L, 61L, 264L, 
    106L, 326L, 278L, 150L, 397L, 398L, 199L, 478L, 430L, 134L, 
    297L, 291L, 341L, 436L, 47L, 94L, 275L, 419L, 448L, 180L, 
    24L, 440L, 135L, 260L, 472L, 158L, 335L, 44L, 442L, 362L, 
    470L, 145L, 384L, 257L, 6L, 333L, 429L, 149L, 62L, 173L, 
    109L, 330L, 492L, 286L, 328L, 178L, 197L, 367L, 282L, 426L, 
    466L, 111L, 123L, 251L)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The only one reply which worked fine so far without any problems! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `purrr` and `dplyr` could be:

```
map2(.x = lst,
     .y = split(1:nrow(lst[[1]]), 
                cut(1:nrow(lst[[1]]), c(0, cumsum(rep(5, length(lst)-1)), Inf))),
     ~ .x %>%
      filter(row_number() %in% .y))
```

Here, the number of rows is the following:

```
$df1
[1] 5

$df2
[1] 5

$df3
[1] 5

$df4
[1] 17
```

Could be a slightly more compact by:

```
df_nrow <- 1:nrow(lst[[1]])
n <- 5

map2(.x = lst,
     .y = split(df_nrow, 
                cut(df_nrow, c(0, cumsum(rep(n, length(lst)-1)), Inf))),
     ~ .x %>%
      filter(row_number() %in% .y))
```

Sample data:

```
lst <- list(df1 = mtcars,
            df2 = mtcars,
            df3 = mtcars,
            df4 = mtcars)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly it assumes that number of rows can be divided by 8 ? I think that my previous comment to other reply will also aplly here "Last data frame in a list is not a subset of last 8 rows. There is still thousands of them left".

Answer (score 1):

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# works also if you have matrices instead of data frames
genDF.a <- genDF.b <- genDF.c <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1:100, 2), nrow = 100))
myList <- list(a = genDF.a, b = genDF.b, c = genDF.c)
```

Now the answer to your question:

```
# put the indices of the rows you want to extract on a list
myInds <- lapply(0:2, function(i) (1:8)+(8*(i)))

# use mapply to loop over both, the list of matrices and the list of indices
mapply(function(M, ind) M[ind,], myList, myInds, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
```

**Edit** based on the comment of @Sotos

```
# use Map to loop over both, the list of matrices and the list of indices
Map(function(M, ind) M[ind,], myList, myInds)
```

You will obtain a list with the desired rows of each matrix along with the names from the original list.

I filled the rows of the data frames with their corresponding index so that it is easy to check it works.

The output:

```
$a
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  5  5
6  6  6
7  7  7
8  8  8

$b
   X1 X2
9   9  9
10 10 10
11 11 11
12 12 12
13 13 13
14 14 14
15 15 15
16 16 16

$c
   X1 X2
17 17 17
18 18 18
19 19 19
20 20 20
21 21 21
22 22 22
23 23 23
24 24 24
```

Comment: FYI, `mapply(,...simplify = FALSE)` is the same as `Map()`

Comment: It works till he last data frame in a list because it takes again first 8 rows. The reason may be that it does not go to the end of number of rows. Last data frame in a list is not a subset of last 8 rows. There is still thousands of them left.

Comment: The indices I've put in my answer were just to give an example, as were also the names and contents of the list. You can replace the vector of factors for anything you want. For your particular case: `myInds <- lapply(0:(length(myList)-1), function(i) (1:8)+(8*(i)))`. You did not take the time to put a minimal reproducible example or tell us what you have tried. At least you should replace your specific data into the solution provided before saying it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` and modify it to your needs, a working example

```
# create some sample data
sample_list <- lapply(1:30, function(i) {

  tibble::tibble(x = i * 1:1000, y = 2 * x)


})

# number of rows to extract/skip
skip_no <- 8

# use lapply with anonymus function
lapply(1:length(sample_list), function(i) {

  # create own variable to set the sample_list index in relation to 
  # the anonymus function argument 'i'

  if (i == 1) {

    current_index <- 1

  } else {

  current_index <- (i - 1) * skip_no + 1

  }


  sample_list[[i]][current_index:(current_index + skip_no - 1),]



})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mapply

```
df=list(a=mtcars,b=mtcars,c=mtcars)
ix=list(1:8,9:16,17:25)
mapply(function(x,y){list(x[y,])},x=df,y=ix)
```

Comment: They have 30 data frames in the list...how are you going to create all the indices manually?

Comment: @Sotos just an example, since no data was given. The ix list can be easily generated from a vector.

Comment: Great. I can't wait to see your technique for generalising. Make sure you go through my answer so we don't post essentially the same thing. (even though I think I overthought it from my end)